# Questions on Scaling an application

Tags: web-applications, scalability

I've been reading a bit about scaling an application. From what I read that, I've gathered that there are 2 types of scaling. 
1. Vertical scaling -- Adding more servers.
2. Horizontal scaling -- Adding more instances of your application.

I didn't quite understand the second one. What does it exactly mean to add more instances of the application. How is this achieved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods of scaling you describe sound like steps for horizontal scaling:

In vertical scaling, you upgrade RAM, storage, processors, networking, etc. on an existing server to improve application performance. However, there are limits to what this type of scaling can accomplish, because one physical server can only hold so much computing power.

In horizontal scaling, you run multiple copies (instances) of the application on additional servers, and use some type of load-balancing system to distribute requests for your app across multiple running versions of your app; this allows you not only to greatly increase the capacity of your application, but also have uninterrupted operation by making maintenance to some servers while always leaving at least some running.

[Docker](https://www.docker.com/) is a container system that (along with much more outside the scope of this question) is often used for horizontal scaling through Docker's 'swarm' mode. Going through their [getting started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) tutorial will walk you through an example docker setup with horizontal scaling, and will at least give you a general idea of how horizontal scaling works.